# How can I pause the execution of code in google script until the entire spreadsheet gets updated?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, sleep

I have a spreadsheet with lots of data and formulae. I am importing a particular cell value from spreadsheet into the google script. However since the cell is not updated with a recent revision, the script is taking the previous value. For now I have given "sleep" in script to temporarily stop the script from running so as to wait for the spreadsheet to get updated. I am not sure if the time that gave in sleep is sufficient in future with the data in spreadsheet increasing continuously.

I would like to know if there is a way to check the status of spreadsheet (updated? updating? etc). I will only run the script when the spreadsheet is updated.

Any help will be highly appreciated. This is the last issue that I reckon could be to finish my task after being struggled in logic, code, triggers etc.

Comment: How about using Flush https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush()

Comment: Hi Anees, how about writing this as an answer so that the question could be "closed" ? ;-)

Comment: @pnuts: Why not edit the question and fix the tags?

Comment: Hi Anees, I tried the code of color change in the link that you sent. I see the colors are changing in a similar way with or without flush(). I am unable to understand what exactly the flush is doing here. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 6):

As Anees mentioned in the comments, the flush() command is what you are looking for.

```
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush()

Comment: I am facing the same issue with another form although "flush" line is added in the code. Is there anything else that is causing this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try using the Utilities.sleep function it allows execution to pause for n milliseconds before continuing.

Comment: This solution is already used in the question and as @surajkumar already said it may not work reliable so he seeks another solution.