# Need to pause script to avoid having date stamp 01/01/1970 due to data loading

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an archiving script which is now working as it should, however when backing up I did get correct date from cell A2 in first sheet but in the other 3 sheets I get 01/01/1970 in date stamp column on archive sheet.  So I assume I need to pause script to allow new page to load date in A2 from sheet name. I have added a pause in line 33 but now i am getting 01/01/70 in all sheets! I have now let it run overnight and when I checked this am I have 01/0/1970 in ll 4 sheets so I am assuming the delay is either not enough or in the wrong place in the script, can anyone help please?

```
    function onOpen() { // This function adds a custom menu to the 
spreadsheet (Backup to archive) so you can run the script from there.
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Backup')
    .addItem('Backup','dataBackup')
    .addToUi();
 }
 function nameOfSpreadsheet()
 {
   var s= SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName().replace(/(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}).*/,'$1');
 return s;
 }

  function dataBackup() {
  var inputSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var archiveSS = 
  SpreadsheetApp.openById('146WU8RghfFqlCpCSX7n6kBAKOyxcpVKt14yhVfvYz-g');
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var sheetNames = ['AM trip', 'PM trip', 'Pool / Beach', 'Night Dive'];
  for (var i = 0; i < sheetNames.length; i++) {

    var inputSheet = inputSS.getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);
    var archiveSheet = archiveSS.getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);

    var date = inputSheet.getRange('A2').getValue(); // Changed to stop 
   inadvertent cell changes, also made text white so not seen.
    var data = 
  inputSheet.getRange('E7:U37').getValues().filter(function(row) { return 
  row[0] !== '' || row[1] !== ''});

    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
        data[x].splice(0, 0, date);
    }
     var getDate = archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), 
   1).getValue();
    var maxRowLength = data.reduce(function(length, row) { return 
    Math.max(length, row.length); }, 0);
    var date = new Date(date); 
    var getDate = new Date(getDate);
    if (getDate.getDate() === "Loading Data...") {
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
     }
    if (getDate.getDate() != date.getDate() || getDate.getMonth() != 
  date.getMonth()) {     

        if (data.length != 0) {
            archiveSheet.insertRowsAfter(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), 
  data.length);
            archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 
  data.length, maxRowLength).setValues(data);
        } else {
            archiveSheet.insertRowsAfter(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), 1);
            archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 
 2).setValues([[date, 'No Data']]);
        }
    }

  }
  }
```

Comment: Since you've implemented  `Utilities.sleep();` already. Try using `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` to applies all pending Spreadsheet changes. This was also stated in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26925055/5995040). If this doesn't help, try adding additional miliseconds in the `utilities.sleep()`.

Comment: I have adjusted the sleep command slightly var date = new Date(date);   if (date.getRange() === "Loading Data...") {
   Utilities.sleep(3000);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();         
 **   if (getDate.getDate() != date.getDate() || getDate.getMonth() != date.getMonth()) {     so that it runs all together but now I get the error "Cannot find function getRange in object Invalid Date. (line 32, " and line with ** is line 32, basically I need it to check cell A2 and if it says "Loading data" it pauses for 5 seconds and then takes the information and uses it in the archive sheet date column.