# Range#sort fails to sort based on new formula's values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am extracting data from several Google Sheets into one main sheet using Google Apps Script. To convert dates to week-numbers I use the sheet function `ISOWEEKNUM()` for column 1. 
I want to sort by week-numbers and because of headers I use [`Range#sort`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj).

The problem I am having is that no sorting is performed when I test run *`getData()`*, the `Range#sort` call has no effect. If I first run *`getData()`* and then manually run my *`sortRange()`* function it works.

Is there something about writing cells with `ISOWEEKNUM()` in them and then try to sort directly in the same script execution? What can be done solve this without the user having to sort or start more scripts manually?

```
function getData()
{
  var thisSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = thisSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Data');
  var deliverySheets = listDeliverySheets();

  var outputWeekAndTotal = [];
  var outputCratesPerStore = [];
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < deliverySheets.length; i++)
  {
    outputWeekAndTotal.push(["=ISOWEEKNUM(\""+deliverySheets[i].getRange("A2").getDisplayValue()+"\")", deliverySheets[i].getRange("L12").getValue()]);
    outputCratesPerStore.push(deliverySheets[i].getRange("L5:L9").getValues());    
  }

  dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, outputWeekAndTotal.length, outputWeekAndTotal[0].length)
    .setValues(outputWeekAndTotal);
  dataSheet.getRange(2, 3, outputCratesPerStore.length, outputCratesPerStore[0].length)
    .setValues(outputCratesPerStore);
  sortRange();
}

function sortRange()
{
  var thisSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rangeToSort = thisSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Data').getRange(2, 1, 7, 7); /*Constants used temporarily*/
  rangeToSort.sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
}
```

Comment: Set frozen rows and then sort the sheet's `DataRange` (frozen rows stay put). You see no sorting because of API call optimization -- your formula isn't yet written. You can force the write-then-sort by either chaining the sort call to the same exact `Range` object (i.e. pass it as a parameter to your `sortRange` function), or by flushing the write buffer prior to calling `sortRange`. Note that using `getRange` with the same parameters does not create the same exact `Range` object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pause the execution of code in google script until the entire spreadsheet gets updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925055/how-can-i-pause-the-execution-of-code-in-google-script-until-the-entire-spreadsh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental issue is that [Google is free to (and does) optimize their interpretation of your code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations) to avoid abuse of their servers. When you call functions that operate on *different* objects, Google doesn't always determine that the order is important, and thus may invoke certain API operations out of (your desired) order. You can help Google by chaining methods on the exact same object, but this is not always sufficient. Operations that cause side effects / asynchronous changes, such as writing a formula, or operate over different APIs - such as calling the Drive API/Service after using Form, Docs, or Sheets Service  methods - may not be performed in order even if "chained."

To fix this, you must forcibly flush the write cache buffer. For the Spreadsheet Service, this is done via a call to [`SpreadsheetApp#flush`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush).

```
  ...
  dataSheet.getRange(...).setValues(...);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  sortRange();
}
```

Flushing the write cache will force the written formulas to be calculated prior to executing the next script lines, making their values available to the sorting method.

Comment: I tried using the changes for chaining the calls using the same Range object all the way, but it did not solve the problem (although it made the code nicer). Adding SpreadsheetApp#flush before sorting however solved the issue.