# Back to back function calls leading to error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am running a simple use case in Google sheets.

1. Import data from a source sheet and paste it in the destination sheet (made a function `importData(sourceSheetURL, destinationSheetURL, destinationSheetName)` for this)
2. Once imported, perform a simple calculation on the data (made a function `cleanData()` for this.

Both of these work fine individually but when I call them back to back from a main function then it throws an error.

```
function main() {
    importData(sourceSheetURL, destinationSheetURL, destinationSheetName);
    cleanData();
}
```

The error has got to do with with the `cleanData()` function as it involves a method `.getLastRow()` that is throwing the error 'Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1.'

I figured this is probably happening because by the time `cleanData()` is called the data from the previous function has not yet been pasted. Hence the `.getLastRow()` not getting any rows error. I tried adding a long delay (much longer than the individual execution time of each of the functions) but got the same error. Using this code also did not resolve the issue.

```
function main() {
    importData(sourceSheetURL, destinationSheetURL, destinationSheetName);
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
    cleanData();
}
```

If I run the `cleanData()` function manually after the data has been imported then there are no issues, so I am guessing this has something to do with the first function not executing in time for the second one to manipulate the data. But I am not able to figure out how to resolve this. Any help will be appreciated.

If it clarifies the problem in any way here are the individual functions.

```
function importData(sourceSheetURL, destinationSheetURL, destinationSheetName) {

    var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sourceSheetURL).getActiveSheet();

    var destinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(destinationSheetURL).getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);

    // Get source data
    var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
    var A1Range = sourceRange.getA1Notation();
    var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();

    // Paste source data
    destinationSheet.clear();
    destinationSheet.getRange(A1Range).setValues(sourceData);
}


function cleanData() { 
  
    // Get index value
    var index = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Controller').getRange(9, 3).getValue();

    // Get imported data
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CAT');
    console.log(ss.getLastRow());
    var rawData = ss.getRange(2, 13, ss.getLastRow()-1).getValues();

    // Index data and paste values
    ss.getRange(1, 17).setValue('Indexed Data');

    for (var i = 0; i < rawSearches.length; i++)   {
      rawData[i] = rawData[i] / index;
      ss.getRange(i+2, 17).setValue(rawData[i]);
    };
}
```

Comment: I would try using a SpreadsheetApp.flush() between them.

Comment: Wow! This worked. I will read up on why this worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/55246464/1595451